# Redirection loop in identity authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am using identity to authenticate users, but I keep getting redirection loop (url is too long) when entering home page.

```
HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     RequestFilteringModule
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler    ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0
Error Code     0x00000000

Physical Path      c:\...\auth\login
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
Request Tracing Directory      C:\...\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\BUDGETINGMANAGER
```

I use visual studio 2013, and have done everything like here- http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1

---

I found solutions to this problem, but none works. I've tried:

1) Enabling anonymous authentication

2) Disabling windows authentication in config.web:

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the maximum length allowed for your query string in both your application and IIS:

Application:

```
<httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" />
```

IIS:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768"/>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxquerystringlength(v=vs.110).aspx

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits

Comment: Now I have a redirection loop.